# Access content in a "private" folder on iOS 8?

Tags: ios, ios8, iphone-6

I would like to load an image from the *Photos* folder at `/private/var/mobile/MEDIA/DCIM/` on iOS 8. (app runs on an iPhone 6)
I noticed the path starts with `private`, is it possible to read content from the folder regardless?
(I'm using Adobe Air and the Air SDK 15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since every app on iOS is sandboxed you will need to access the photos by using the appropriate system API.

Take a look at the Photos Framework Reference to get started. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/Photos_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014408